# Subset and Filter from lapply()

Tags: r, filter, subset

I am running a loop using the lapply function in R, which I have successfully done! I am now trying to create a new data frame with these results using the subset function, particularly the "[,]" bracket notation. After I do this, I am trying to filter the data frame for values < 0.2. How can I subset this?

To clarify, I want to convert the column names (2:256) of m3 and make them each a row of column 1 titles "Gene". I then want to include the p-value, which I found using the lapply function as a 2nd column.

The m3 data frame looks like:

```
Sample ID       P53     BRCA     PTEN   Status      Overall Survival
 1              0         0        1       1           12
 2              1         0        0       0           2.4
```

...

For instance I would like for it to look like this:

```
Gene         P-Value
P53          0.53
BRCA         0.0004
PTEN         0.1
```

...

```
m4 <- data.frame(lapply(m3[, 2:256], function(i) {s <- 
survdiff(Surv(m3$Overall.Survival, m3$Status) ~ i) 
pchisq(s$chisq, length(unique(i)) - 1L, lower.tail = FALSE)}))


m5 <- data.frame(t(m4))
names(m5)[1]<-"P-Value"
```

I ended up generating a new data frame, but there aren't any numbers on the left hand side so I don't think I did this properly.

Comment: Using your supplied data, and library survival,  the lapply fails with error `survdiff.fit(y, groups, strata.keep, rho) : There is only 1 group` after correcting typo `2:ncol(m)` to `2:ncol(m3)`. Take a look at function `gather `in library `tidyr` to get to the vertical format.

Comment: @epi99 I updated the lapply code to work properly.